# Resetting ArcPy 'for' loop when using SearchCursor on shapefile

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am comparing the data in two shapefile Ex: Existing.Shp and UpdatedRecently.shp.
Existing.shp files has 3110 Records and Updated.shp has 410 records total and 110 duplicated records from Existing.shp.

Logic:

Location and Date Field was taken using SearchCursor and parsing in Updated.shp for finding and removing Duplicate records [110 records]. The remaining 300 records have to be added in Existing.shp file.

Error:

For Loop- It's not resetting to first row.

Code:

```py
import arcpy
import datetime

Existing = r"E:\ExistingCopy.shp"
Updated = r"E:\Updated.shp"
field = ["FID", "Name", "NameLong", "created_us", "created_da"]
rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Existing, field)
Updatedrows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Updated, field)
strLocationTemp = "London"
dtnow = datetime.datetime.now()
tdy = dtnow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
for row in rows:
    if strLocationTemp in row[1] and row[4] is not None:
        tdy = row[4]
        print(row[0],row[4],tdy)
        for Updatedrow in Updatedrows:
            if tdy == Updatedrow[4]:
                print(tdy)
```

Comment: Where in your code do you request that the cursor be reset?  Best practice here with so few rows would be to load both tables into memory.  There might be efficiencies to be had by sorting both lists on one or more fields, but no way to tell with the information given.

Comment: I think you need to instantiate the cursors each time you run through the rows.  The cursors can't go backward, for lack of a better explanation.  They aren't like a list, where you can just re-loop through it over and over.

Comment: Something like this `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(eraser,["SHAPE@"]) as ecur:
    for e in ecur:
        eraseList.append(e[0])`

Comment: Another example, starting with a for loop:  `for e in eraseList:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(target, ["SHAPE@"]) as polygons:
        for polygon in polygons:
            if e.disjoint(polygon[0])==False:
                polygons.updateRow([polygon[0].difference(e)])`

Comment: It's generally bad practice to use nested cursors, this usually results in poor performance.    Consider creating a dictionary out of UpdatedRows to use for a lookup

Comment: If you want to add new records to an existing data set, you should be using [InsertCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) and not an UpdateCursor.  UpdateCursor is for updating records that already exist, not for updating a data set with new records.